# Laravel - WYSIWYG editor max character validation

Tags: laravel, validation, summernote

I am using WYSIWYG editor (summernote to be specific). Is there easy way to validate max characters for text coming from it **with stripped tags** without using `Validator` class and after that store text **with** tags into db? I managed to achieve this storing it into temporary variable but maybe there is better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate a request in a controller like so:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'wysiwyg_value' => 'required|max:500'
]);
```

The [validate method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) is on the Request object.

Comment: Well it wasn't very clear that the tags weren't already stripped. What you need to do is create a custom form request that strips the tags, then you can use the above code.

Comment: if I strip tags I may as well use regular textarea

Comment: Could you please clarify your question then because it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you make it clearer it's more likely someone will be able to help you find the answer.